# Not required VAT field

Tags: magento-1.9, vat

How can I disable the required VAT field in billing step and registration with Magento 1.9?
Thanks

Comment: RESOLVED: I put "NULL" in field "is_required" with attribute_id=15 in database table "customer_eav_attribute_website"!

Comment: is it proper way.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change this behaviour at System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Name  and Address Options

Comment: Ok, I see "Show Tax/VAT Number" with "Optional" (it's my selected item) but if I put "No" or "Required", I alway see the VAT required field with "*". Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the customer attribute extension from magento connect. 
Here is the link; http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html

But i never tried to delete vat attribute. Share the result with us will you?
Thanks.

Comment: I have Magento 1.9.